# Number Guessing Program issue Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having trouble with this assignment that I have been given(High School). It's a number guessing game and I have already gotten most of it down, but he wants us to put a range of numbers  on the console. An example output would be:

Enter lower limit: 4

Enter Upper limit: 10

Etc, basically choose the specific range of numbers you want the computer to choose from.  I have only been able to code in a set range(1-1000) since I can't figure out how to do what he wants. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Game {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumber;
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);           
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
 do {
            System.out.print("Enter a guess (1-1000): ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (guess == randomNumber)
  System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");
    else if (guess < randomNumber)
       System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");
  else if (guess > randomNumber)
 System.out.println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");
        } while (guess != randomNumber);
  }
```

}

If you try it it is also really hard to play anyway. I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: What do you think this expression is doing: `(int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1)`? How would you change it to get another range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For random number in range, you have two options:

```
Random rand = new Random();
// nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
// so add 1 to make it inclusive
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Or in java 1.7 or later:

```
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I had pretty much the same solution ready, but you posted first. ):  I'll still up-vote though, because your answer is correct

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the user to set the range you will need to implement another line where you ask the user for the range

`Scanner min= new Scanner(System.in);` and `Scanner max = new Scanner(System.in);`

then in this line of your code `randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);` you can now set the range you would like with the user input `random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("enter minimum");
  int min= keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("enter maximum");
  int max= keyboard.nextInt();
  int randomNumber= (int) (Math.random()* max + min);
  int guess;
  do {
     System.out.print("Enter a guess (1-1000): ");
     guess = keyboard.nextInt();

     if (guess == randomNumber)
        System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");
     else if (guess < randomNumber)
        System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");
     else if (guess > randomNumber)
        System.out.println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");
   } while (guess != randomNumber);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well, you are all very helpful!